# Expected ';' before 'currentNode'

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
void llInsertAfter(list* myList, node *insNode, std::string *toStore)
{
    node node;
    node.value = *toStore;
    if(llSize(myList) == 0)
    {
        (myList -> head) = &node;
        (myList -> tail) = &node;
    }
    else
    {
        node currentNode = *(myList -> head);
        while(currentNode.value != (insNode -> value))
        {
            currentNode = *(currentNode.next);
        }
        if(currentNode.next == NULL)
        {
        currentNode.next = &node;
        }
        else
        {
            node.next = currentNode.next;
            currentNode.next = &node;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is error message

```
llist.cpp:73:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘aa’
   node aa = *(myList -> head);
```

I can't see why this error happen.

Comment: How `node` was declared in this context?

Comment: There's no `node aa` in the code you posted.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not some piece of code that does not make sense for the error to be about it.

Comment: `node currentNode = *(myList -> head)` etc - if `head` is just a pointer then that is copying the contents of the node, not taking a pointer to it. If you modify `currentNode` nothing will happen to your list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
node node;
```

After that, the name `node` refers to the local variable, not the type. Since it's a class type, you could refer to it as `class node` or `struct node` thereafter; but a better option might be to use a different name for the variable.